# Stability of a Modified Numerical Scheme for a Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The problem is to prove the modified scheme $\frac{U^{n+1}_{m} - U^{n-1}_{m}}{2k} + a\delta_{0}(\frac{U^{n+1}_{m} +4U^{n}_{m} +U^{n-1}_{m}}{6})=0$ for the one way wave equation $u_{t}+au_{x}=0$ is stable if and only if $|a\lambda| < \sqrt{3}$.

I found the roots of the amplification equation as $g_{1} = \frac{-2ib+\sqrt{-3b^2 + 1}}{1+ib}$ and $g_{2} = \frac{-2ib-\sqrt{-3b^2 + 1}}{1+ib}$ where $b = \frac{a\lambda sin(\theta)}{3}$.

I know If $g_{1} = g_{2} = g$, then $U^{n} = c_{1}g^{n} + c_{2}ng^{n-1}$

Also, If $g_{1} \neq g_{2}$, then $U^{n} = c_{1}g^{n}_{1} + c_{2}g^{n}_{2}$

Now I need to consider cases:

Case $1$: $|a\lambda| = \sqrt{3} $

Case $2$: $|a\lambda | > \sqrt{3}$

Case $3$: $|a\lambda | < \sqrt{3}$

I am not sure how to consider these cases.

Comment: What are $k, \lambda, \theta$? I assume that $\delta_0$ is the central difference operator?

Comment: Yes sorry, $\lambda = \frac{k}{h}$. Yes $\delta_{0} $is the central difference operator.

Answer (score 0):

The amplification equation is
$$
\frac{g^2 - 1}{2k} + a \frac{e^{i\theta} - e^{-i\theta}}{2}
\frac{g^2 + 4g + 1}{6} = 0
$$
Introducing $b = \frac{ak\sin \theta}{3}$ one obtains
$$
g^2 - 1 + ib (g^2 + 4 g + 1) = 0\\
(1 + ib)g^2 + 4ibg - (1 - ib) = 0
$$
From the Viete theorem,
$$
g_1 g_2 = -\frac{1 - ib}{1+ib}\\
g_1 + g_2 = \frac{4ib}{1 + ib}
$$
The first implies
$$
|g_1| |g_2| = \left|-\frac{1-ib}{1+ib}\right| = 1,
$$
so the scheme is stable iff $|g_1| = |g_2|$ for every $\theta$ (i.e. $\forall b \in [-\frac{ak}{3}, \frac{ak}{3}]$). Note that $b$ is real. The case $g_1 = g_2$ should be treated separately.

Consider cases when $\frac{\mathscr D}{4} = -4b^2 + (1 + b^2) = 1-3b^2$ is negative, positive and zero:

- $\mathscr D > 0 \; (b^2 < \frac{1}{3})$, 
  $$
  g_{1,2} = \frac{-2ib \pm \sqrt{1 - 3b^2}}{1 + ib},
  |g_{1,2}| = \frac{4b^2 + (1 - 3b^2)}{1 + b^2}
  $$
  Stable, since $g_1 \neq g_2, |g_1| = |g_2| = 1$.
- $\mathscr D = 0 \; (b^2 = \frac{1}{3})$
  $$
  g_1 = g_2 = \frac{2i}{\sqrt{3} + i}, |g_1| = |g_2| = 1
  $$
  Unstable, since $n g^n \to \infty$
- $\mathscr D < 0 \; (b^2 > \frac{1}{3})$ 
  $$
  g_{1,2} = \frac{-2ib \pm i\sqrt{3b^2 - 1}}{1 + ib},
  |g_{1,2}| = \frac{(2b \pm \sqrt{3b^2 - 1})^2}{1 + b^2} = 
  \frac{7b^2 - 1 \pm 4b\sqrt{3b^2 - 1}}{1 + b^2}\\
  |g_1| \neq |g_2|
  $$
  Unstable, if $|g_1| < 1$ then $|g_2| > 1$ and vice versa. The case $|g_1| = |g_2| = 1$ is impossible.

Finally, the solution is bounded iff $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}< b < \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. The $[-\frac{ak}{3}, \frac{ak}{3}]$ fits in that interval iff $ak < \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: That is very cool. We have not discussed Viete Theorem, so I will have to look that up.